# Association Clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have the following associations

```
User - has_many :campaigns
Campaign - has_many :donations
           belongs_to :user
Donation - belongs_to :campaign
```

As a user I would like to get the sum of all donations made for the campaigns that the current_user has created, so I tried this

```
@campaigns = current_user.campaigns
@total_donations = @campaigns.dontations.sum('donation_amount')
```

but it's not as simple as that is it, as I have to loop through each of the campaigns belonging to that user. Is that correct?

What's the best way to approach this? Would a scope or instance method be better also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`has_many :through` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :donations, through: campaigns
end

current_user.donations.sum(:donation_amount)
```

Comment: thank you @Stefan, thats done the trick, my mistake was trying to access through the campaigns model when i didnt need to i guess ?

Comment: Which @Stefan did can be done with `Donation.joins(:campaigns).where(campaings: { user_id: <user_id> }).sum(:donation_ammount)`. The `has_many` class method enables the shorthand. +1